# awk 1-liner to cover match and non-matchng cas

Tags: awk

Is there a way in an awk one-liner to cover both the positive and negative match case with different print statements?

To illustrate. Let's say I have a file where I want to prepend a set of words with '#' but still want to print all the words in the file.

Something like :

```
awk '/red/||/green/ { print "# My mod : " $0 } else { print $0 }'
```

Of course the above wont work. But what's the simple way to do this in awk.

Cheers,
Gert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cover the general case i.e. printing something completely different, you can use `next`:

```
awk '/red|green/ { print "foo"; next } { print "bar" }' file
```

The second block is only reached if the first pattern is false.

You can also use `if`/`else` within a single action block.

For your specific case, where you are just adding to the record and printing, you can use this:

```
awk '/red|green/ { $0 = "# My mod : " $0 } 1' file
```

The `1` at the end ensures that every record is printed.

Answer (score 1):

How about "painful" long hand

```
awk '{if (/red/||/green/ ) { print "# My mod : " $0 } else { print $0 }}'
```

That works for me ;-), but you can save a few chars typing with

```
awk '{if (/red|green/ ) {print "# My mod : " $0 } else {print $0} }'
```

OR

```
awk '{print ($0~/red|green/) ? "# My mod : $0 " : "" $0}'
```

Which is the shortest amt of code I can think of to achieve the result you are looking for.

Comment: I concede the shortest-code solution to @TomFenech ;-) 39 chars, vs 51 ;-) . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ print (/red|green/ ? "# My mod : " : "") $0 }' file
```